# cocoeval change the number of keypoints and self.kpt_oks_sigmas into 14 but receive error

Tags: python, evaluation, transformer-model

I am trying to create keypoints detection using transformer and cocoapi. For evaluation, I use cocoeval and change the "self.kpt_oks_sigmas" from 17 into 14:

```
self.kpt_oks_sigmas = np.array([.26, .25, .25, .35, .35, .79, .79, .72, .72, .62,.62, 
                     1.07, 1.07, .87, .87, .89, .89])/10.0
```

into

```
self.kpt_oks_sigmas = np.array([1.07, .87, .89, 1.07, .87, .89, 1., 1., .79, .72, .62, .79, .72, .62])/10.0
```

However, I received error message that says:

[image: error message]

Does anyone knows what should I do to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Kernel helps for me.

For some reason when you change cocoeval.py file, changes doesn`t apply immediately, only after restarting kernel.